# Highcharts conflict with extjs

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to render 3 highcharts inside the extjs tab using prototype adapter. I am rendering multiple bar charts in a single page all having click event on the bars. All charts that render below the first bar charts do not get the click event that i have registered for them. The first chart on the page has all the click event. But all the charts below are not click-able even though i have added click events for them. When I render the same page outside an extjs component all the charts and all the clicks work fine. I am guessing there is conflict with highcharts and extjs.

Was able to replicate the issue in jsfilddle http://jsfiddle.net/kNPeg/4/

The following is the javascript code where I am creating the extjs component in which the same highchart is rendered 3 times but the bottom to charts have bars that are not clickable.

```
            var centerTabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
                       region:'center',
                       margins: '0 10 0 0',
                       id:'center-panel',           
                       activeTab:0,
                       bodyStyle:'padding: 8 5 5 8;',
                       autoScroll: true,
               items:[  {
                                        contentEl: 'db_snapshots',
                                        title: "Charts",
                                        autoScroll: true,
                                        bodyStyle: 'background:#fffff0;padding: 8 5 5 8;'
                                    }
                        ]
                    });  


                    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                        layout:'border',
                                    loadMask : {msg:"testLoading..."},
                                    monitorResize : true,
                        items:[


                            centerTabPanel
                                    ]
                    });
                            viewport.doLayout();


            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: "container",
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false

                    },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['First','Second','Third']
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name:"Values",
                            data: [133, 156, 947]
                        }],
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation: false,
                                cursor: 'text',
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function() {
                                            alert("hello");
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            line: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            },
                            bar: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'String',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        }

                });



                 var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: "container2",
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false

                    },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['First','Second','Third']
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name:"Values",
                            data: [133, 156, 947]
                        }],
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation: false,
                                cursor: 'text',
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function() {
                                            alert("hello");
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            line: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            },
                            bar: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'String',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        }

                });

                var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: "container3",
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false

                    },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['First','Second','Third']
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name:"Values",
                            data: [133, 156, 947]
                        }],
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation: false,
                                cursor: 'text',
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function() {
                                            alert("hello");
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            line: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            },
                            bar: {
                                size:'100%',
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'String',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        }

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting point click, you can use workaround, and iterate on each series element (in each chart) and add action to SVG element by "on" trigger.

http://jsfiddle.net/kNPeg/5/

```
 for (var i = 0; i < chart3.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            chart3.series[0].data[i].graphic.on('click', function () {
                alert('aaa3');
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.